# C, Code:Block, yet another sigsegv, lists

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

Good Day everyone, 
Got this exercize from my prof webspace. I have this kind of text file:

```
Simon Phillips 30
Neil Peart 45
Vinnie Colaiuta 50
```

I want to store this into a list so here is my code:

```
struct listplot {
  char name[25];
  char sur[25];
  int age;
  struct listplot *next;
};

typedef struct listplot EL;

EL *list;

int filescan(EL *current)
{
    FILE *in;
    int count=0;
    in=fopen("persone.txt", "r");
    if (ferror(in))
    {
        printf("File Error\n");
        return count;
    }
    do
    {
        current=malloc(sizeof(EL));
        fscanf(in,"%s%s%d", current->name, current->sur, &current->age);
        current->next=NULL;
        if (!feof(in)) count=count+filescan(current->next);
    }
    while (!feof(in));
    return count;
}
```

In `main` i have:

```
int count=filescan(list);
```

This code won't work.
In debug it seems that the 'do' loop goes infinite, but eventually the program crashes with segmentation fault.
Can anybody help me with this? 
Thank you a lot.

Comment: DO NOT read strings without giving a maximum length. And do not assume that a read succeeds.

Comment: DO NOT recurse your filescan function!

Comment: Why shouldn't I recurse? And why shouldn't it succeed?

Comment: You are opening the file infinite times with your recursion, and always read the first line, and other errors...

Comment: you recursively open files, your call stack increase when it doesn't have to.

Comment: Is there any way to avoid this still using recursion?

Comment: create a separate process line function.

Comment: Could I open the file outside the filescan?

Comment: Given the way you've written `filescan()` — ignoring the recursion — you need `EL list; int count = filescan(&list);` to get the information back to your calling function.

Comment: Yes; you can open the file outside the filescan function; that is a better way of doing.  Pass a `FILE *fp` argument to `filescan()`.

Comment: Other comments, Initialize your list to NULL, and add an additional level of indirection to your filescan function to allow the function to create a new EL.

Check your fscanf for returning 3 outputs, otherwise you may need to change "%s" because it may accept the complete line as a single string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Many improvents to make it more robust:

Initialize this element properly:

```
EL* list_header = NULL; /* Points to first element */
```

Increase level of indirection here:

```
int filescan(EL** current)
{
```

In the main function you have to pass the address of the list_header:

```
count = filescan(&list_header)
```

Move this section into a single function whose only concern is to open the file.

```
FILE *in;
int count=0;
in=fopen("persone.txt", "r");
if (ferror(in))
{
    printf("File Error\n");
    return count;
}
```

And return 0 if in is NULL or in error.

```
do
{
```

First do the scan and check if it fills 3 parameters by

```
    EL els = {0}; /* element for scanning */

    if (fscanf(in,"%s%s%d", els.name, els.sur, &els.age) == 3)
    {
```

Move this in to a function that creates/fills/copies a new EL for a successfully filled els

```
current->next = create_duplicate_EL_for(els);

/* the duplicator should malloc and fill, and set next to NULL */
    current=malloc(sizeof(EL));
    // some strcpys //
    current->next=NULL;
```

Apparently you want count so increase it.

And for looping, set

```
current = current->next;
```

Complete your scanf branch with an else if we don't find exactly 3 elements:

```
    else
    {
        /* debug/error log code here */
    }
}
while (!feof(in));
return count;
```

Comment: If i change `filescan(EL *current` to `filescan(EL** current` i get this error `error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union`, the same goes for sur and age

Comment: Then you need to dereference it with either current->name or (*current).name.